# IntelliJ IDEA claiming that error exists but it doesn't

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, intellij-14

I am having issues with IntelliJ iDEA, there is an error claiming:

```
Error:(158, 112) java: incompatible types: inference variable U has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: javafx.collections.ObservableList<com.neonorb.derby_pro.core.Car>
upper bounds: javafx.collections.ObservableList<com.neonorb.derby_pro.ui.gui.Car>,java.lang.Object
```

There is only one error, but as soon as I comment out that line, the two lines above it get similar errors (Using `IntegerProperty` and `ObjectProperty`). If I move the binding a little further up in the code (above some other bindings), the two bindings that I talked about earlier, get errors, then fix themselves, but this one still has a problem. I have had this same problem before, but managed to fix it somehow. Possibly a bug?

Here is the line:

```
carsProperty.bind(EasyBind.select(gui.getCore().getDerbyManager().derbyProperty()).selectObject(Derby::carsProperty));
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is the `carsProperty` declaration:

```
private ObjectProperty<ObservableList<Car>> carsProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty();
```

And here is the `Derby.carsProperty` declaration:

```
private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<ObservableList<Car>> carsProperty = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(carExtractor()));

public ReadOnlyProperty<ObservableList<Car>> carsProperty() {
    return carsProperty.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

Comment: I found a workaround, just put the EasyBind binding as a variable and bind to that. Any other ideas on why this happens?